# How to add/close a shortcode to functions.php in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

How would I go about adding the following shortcode properly to functions.php in WordPress? When I add it works but it isn't closed properly and gives me an error.

```html
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[brb_collection id="297"]' ); ?>
```

I am getting the following error:

"Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 55 of file wp-content/themes/betheme-child/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file"

Here is my functions.php

```html
<?php

// // Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_locale_css( $uri ){
        if ( empty( $uri ) && is_rtl() && file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/rtl.css' ) )
            $uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css';
        return $uri;
    }
endif;
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION

/* Tillad at uploade fonts */

function wp39550_disable_real_mime_check( $data, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
 $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );

 $ext = $wp_filetype['ext'];
 $type = $wp_filetype['type'];
 $proper_filename = $data['proper_filename'];

 return compact( 'ext', 'type', 'proper_filename' );
}
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wp39550_disable_real_mime_check', 10, 4 );

/* CF7 redirects */

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );
 
function redirect_cf7() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   if ( '117' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends sumissions on form 947 to the first thank you page
    location = 'https://example.com/thank-you/';
    } else if ( '118' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
        location = 'https://example.com/thank-you/';
    } else if ( '541' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
        location = 'https://example.com/da/tak/';
    } else if ( '542' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
        location = 'https://example.com/da/tak/';  
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}

/* Google reivew widget */

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[brb_collection id="297"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: You'll probably need to show the code in  wp-content/themes/betheme-child/functions.php here.

Comment: Seems like your functions.php is ending with an unexpected character. Can you add the end / last view lines of your functions.php file?

Comment: Very unclear what you're trying to do here.  Are you trying to use the shortcode "brb_collection" on a page, or are you trying to add a function that filters out shortcodes?

Comment: I am trying to add the shortcode from a plugin as it'll display a Google Reviews widget on all pages of my site.  have edited the post with all of my functions.php code to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You’re reopening php, while already in a php section

Just remove the php opening tag right before your last echo

Or close the previous php section before the comment
/* Google reivew widget */

Comment: Hey Giovanni, thanks for your answer. I removed the php before echo and now it doesn't give me an error but then the review widget shows up weirdly in the header whereas before it showed up correctly but it gave me an error.

Comment: Sounds like your shortcode is echoing content, while it should return content, have a look at the shortcode..

Comment: How would you do this?